# Wrong pinch direction on a FocalTech touchpad

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, gestures, focaltech

I'm using a FocalTech touchpad (Asus R556LB)

It wasn't detected by default so I installed the 4.1.2 kernel. Now almost all the gestures but the pinch gesture are detected correctly.

When I move the two fingers apart in order to zoom in, the content zooms out (in Firefox I have to keep control pressed)

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What is Ubuntu version? How did you setup zoom feature? These features are not related to the kernel driver. They are implemented in user space drivers.

Comment: I'm using the 14.04 packages. It worked out of the box after installing 4.1.2 (at least on Cinnamon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinch gesture is not supported in Ubuntu, at least without special setup.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and trying to pinch is actually two-finger scrolling. That results in scaling in browsers.

Comment: In Google Maps the zoom is present too (and inverted as well)

Comment: As I said it is not pinch at all. Just move two fingers up or down with pressed Ctrl.

Comment: In embedded Google Maps the pinch gesture works (in an inverted way) even without control.

Comment: The third time: this is not pinch. In Gmaps just scrolling is zoom. Same as e.g. in evince. Am I not clear? Did you try just scrolling?

Comment: And is it possible to set it up manually?

Comment: As far as I know in Ubuntu with unity it is not possible. With other DE with libinput it must be.

Comment: I'm not using Unity anyway (Cinnamon instead)

Comment: You are right, it is indeed scrolling